# I lost reference to my propertie in view model

Tags: swift, mvvm

I get the dates from API, this is ok, but when i set the propertie Fund, i lost reference.

This is make with Swift 5 with class Result to use the completion, but i lost the reference, i can get date but i cant pass to view model

View Model

```swift
class FundViewModel {
    var fund: Fund?

    init() {
        FundService.getScreen(completion: ({ (result) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                return
            case .success(let fundSucess):
                self.fund = fundSucess
            }

        }))
    }
```

Controller

```swift
    var usedView: UIView = FundView()

    var fundViewModel: FundViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        setupBinding()
    }

    fileprivate func setupBinding() {
        self.fundViewModel = FundViewModel()
if let fundView = usedView as? FundView {fundView.fundViewModel = self.fundViewModel}
    }
```

View

```swift
  var fundViewModel: FundViewModel! {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = fundViewModel.fund.title
        }
    }
```

I want to pass the content from view model to didSet at View

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: It is a bad idea to perform asynchronous operations in an initialiser since you are left with an uninitialised object until some time after the initialiser completes. This is the problem you are experiencing; you are accessing properties of the object before the asynchronous operation finishes. Your view model should expose an appropriate "fetch" method that accepts a completion handler so that your code can process the object once it has been fetched

Comment: In view model where i can put this fetch? because all content pass through the init

Comment: The code will just be a function in your view model class. You will need to perform this fetch at an appropriate point in your code. Alternatively you might like to create a network operation object that has a function that returns an instance of `Fund` via a closure and uses that to initialise a view model

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help